# Data ingestion from Rest API using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

As part of a POC i need to get data from REST API end point that return JSON data as Response and then save it AS-IS into Azure SQL database.

This REST API will be used for both Historical (Around 10000 records expected) and incremental load that will be executing at some regular intervals. Rest API use OAuth 2.0 access token for Authorization

Please let me know the best options available for doing data ingestion in Azure , should i use ADF or Azure functions and what are the best practices for configuring REST API in ADF in particular to error handling.

If this POC works successfully i need to integrate few more API calls into the design as well.

Comment: What about your interval period for this schedule ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post yesterday on this topic, using DataFactory to pull data from a rest API.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-data-factory-copy-from-rest-api-sql-database-rohit-vangala

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The blog shows how to configure the rest copy activity, but has no info on error handling and uses only basic authentication.